# Ignore the first row when running the macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below macro to transfer data from one sheet to another. However I need the first row to be the date (date modified) so I need the macro to ignore the top row. I've looked online but can't seem to find the solution?

```
Sub HistoricMD()

    ActiveSheet.Range("K7:K15").Copy
    Sheets("Historic MD").Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

On another note I've just added

```
=IF(B2 >0,NOW(),"")
```

to get the date modified, any other better solutions would be good!

Thank you :)

Comment: Which "first row" you want to ignore? You already move one row down and one column right with `Offset(1,1)`. Can you provide a screenshot with your worksheet and expected result maybe?
The "date modified" function is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just change this:

```
Sheets("Historic MD").Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlValues
```

To this:

```
Sheets("Historic MD").Range("IV2").End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlValues
```

Answer (score 0):

Alter as follows: We will paste in row 2 (as you did already, using offset), and manually put the date in row 1:

```
Sub HistoricMD()

    ActiveSheet.Range("K7:K15").Copy
    Sheets("Historic MD").Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlValues
    Sheets("Historic MD").Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).value = Date
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome. Please mark the question as answered then. Thanks.